# HTML Email Signature - Table contents not aligned when sent in Outlook Email Client

Tags: html, html-email, text-alignment, email-client

Junior Web Dev here, first HTML email sig I've been asked to do, so thanks for your patience.

Having a display issue - first line in the table is out of alignment when viewed in email clients (Outlook 365) and I really don't know why. When I run the code on here it displays correctly.

Image and code below.

Please help!!!

Thanks in advance,
Libby

[Email client display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZEBb.png)

```html
<style type="text/css">
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700);
    body{margin:0;padding:0;width:100% !important;}
    img {outline:none;text-decoration:none;border:none;}
    p {margin:0px !important;}
    a {color:inherit !important;text-decoration:none !important;}
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .hidden-mobile {
    display: none;
    }
    }
</style>

                    
<table width="640" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
            <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#000000"><table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                          <tbody>

                                                        <tr>
                              <td><span style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:16px; font-weight:700; color:#fff; text-transform:uppercase;">Libby Stonehawk</span></td>
                              </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td valign="top" style="padding-top:5px;"><span style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:16px; font-weight:400; color:#d6e3e1; text-transform:uppercase;">Website Manager</span></td>
                              </tr>


                            </tbody>
                          </table></td>
                                                    <td bgcolor="#000000"><table width="10%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                        <tbody>





                                                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                                                        <td width="112" align="right"><img src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/kallumslogotrans-white-2.png" width="auto" height="auto" alt=""/></td>
                                                                                                                     </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table></td>


                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table></td>
                  </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="60%" bgcolor="#EFEFEF" style="padding:10px 0;"><table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td width="24"><img src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/icon-map_dark.png" width="16" height="16" alt=""/></td>
                                    <td style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:14px; font-weight:400; color:#647875;"><p stlye="margin:0 !important">100 Lower Richmond Road, London, SW15 1LN</p></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table></td>
                              </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td width="24"><img src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/icon-phone_dark.png" width="16" height="16" alt=""/></td>
                                    <td style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:14px; font-weight:400; color:#524e4e;"><a href="tel:" style="color:#524e4e !important; text-decoration:none !important;"><span style="color:#647875; text-decoration:none;">07941073079</span></a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table></td>
                              </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td width="24"><img src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/icon-email_dark.png" width="16" height="16" alt=""/></td>
                                    <td style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:14px; font-weight:400; color:#647875;"><a href="mailto:" style="color:#647875 !important; text-decoration:none !important;"><span style="color:#647875; text-decoration:none;">libby@kallumsbathrooms.co.uk</span></a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table></td>
                              </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td width="24"><img src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/icon-web_dark.png" width="16" height="16" alt=""/></td>
                                    <td style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:14px; font-weight:400; color:#647875;"><a href="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/" style="color:#647875 !important; text-decoration:none !important;"><span style="color:#647875; text-decoration:none;">kallumsbathrooms.co.uk</span></a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table></td>
                              </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table></td>
                        <td width="40%" style="padding:10px 0;"><table width="60%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td width="24"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/social-facebook_dark.png" width="16" height="16" alt=""/></a></td>
                                    <td style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:14px; font-weight:400; color:#647875;"><p stlye="margin:0 !important">/kallumsbathrooms</p></td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td width="24"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/social-twitter_dark.png" width="16" height="16" alt=""/></a></td>
                                    <td style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:14px; font-weight:400; color:#647875;"><p stlye="margin:0 !important">@KallumsBathroom</p></td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td width="24"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/kallumsbathrooms/?hl=en" target="_blank"><img src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/social-instagram_dark.png" width="16" height="16" alt=""/></a></td>
                                    <td style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:14px; font-weight:400; color:#647875;"><p stlye="margin:0 !important">@kallumsbathrooms</p></td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td width="24" style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:14px; font-weight:700; color:#384241;"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/social-pinterest_dark.png" width="16" height="16" alt=""/></a></td>
                                    <td style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:14px; font-weight:400; color:#647875;"><p stlye="margin:0 !important">/kallumsbathroom</p></td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table width="640" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            
                    <td width="640px" valign="center"><img src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Slider-Test-3-1024x597-8.jpg" width="640px" height="auto" alt=""/></td>
                 </tr>
        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: What email client do you use? I'm tested with [Papercut](https://github.com/ChangemakerStudios/Papercut-SMTP) software and it works fine. ( https://postimg.cc/2159WWQ1 )

Comment: How curious! Thank you for checking for me.

I'm using Microsoft Outlook 365

Comment: This is what happen on [Gmail](https://postimg.cc/8Fk4FK38) and this is on [outlook.com](https://postimg.cc/62pWTvC6). The table maybe as simple like [this](https://postimg.cc/BtNFhTmp). However, I find that the HTML can be render different on each email client. Design should by very basic and simple because the CSS is very limited on those email clients.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
  @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700);
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  
  img {
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
  }
  
  p {
    margin: 0px !important;
  }
  
  a {
    color: inherit !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
  }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .hidden-mobile {
      display: none;
    }
  }
</style>


<table width="640" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tbody>
            <td>
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#000000">
                              <table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tbody>

                                  <tr>
                                    <td><span style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:16px; font-weight:700; color:#fff; text-transform:uppercase;">Libby
                                        Stonehawk</span></td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" style="padding-top:5px;"><span style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:16px; font-weight:400; color:#d6e3e1; text-transform:uppercase;">Website
                                        Manager</span></td>
                                  </tr>

                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                            <td bgcolor="#000000">
                              <table width="10%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td width="112" align="right"><img src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/kallumslogotrans-white-2.png" width="auto" height="auto" alt="" /></td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td width="60%" bgcolor="#EFEFEF" style="padding:10px 0;">
                              <table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td width="24"><img src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/icon-map_dark.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" /></td>
                                            <td style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:14px; font-weight:400; color:#647875;">
                                              <p stlye="margin:0 !important">100 Lower Richmond Road, London, SW15 1LN
                                              </p>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td width="24"><img src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/icon-phone_dark.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" /></td>
                                            <td style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:14px; font-weight:400; color:#524e4e;">
                                              <a href="tel:" style="color:#524e4e !important; text-decoration:none !important;"><span
                                                  style="color:#647875; text-decoration:none;">07941073079</span></a>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td width="24"><img src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/icon-email_dark.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" /></td>
                                            <td style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:14px; font-weight:400; color:#647875;">
                                              <a href="mailto:" style="color:#647875 !important; text-decoration:none !important;"><span
                                                  style="color:#647875; text-decoration:none;">libby@kallumsbathrooms.co.uk</span></a>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td width="24"><img src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/icon-web_dark.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" /></td>
                                            <td style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:14px; font-weight:400; color:#647875;">
                                              <a href="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/" style="color:#647875 !important; text-decoration:none !important;"><span
                                                  style="color:#647875; text-decoration:none;">kallumsbathrooms.co.uk</span></a>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                            <td width="40%" style="padding:10px 0;">
                              <table width="60%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td valign="top">
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td width="24">
                                              <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/social-facebook_dark.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" /></a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:14px; font-weight:400; color:#647875;">
                                              <p stlye="margin:0 !important">/kallumsbathrooms</p>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td valign="top">
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td width="24">
                                              <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/social-twitter_dark.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" /></a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:14px; font-weight:400; color:#647875;">
                                              <p stlye="margin:0 !important">@KallumsBathroom</p>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td valign="top">
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td width="24">
                                              <a href="https://www.instagram.com/kallumsbathrooms/?hl=en" target="_blank"><img src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/social-instagram_dark.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" /></a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:14px; font-weight:400; color:#647875;">
                                              <p stlye="margin:0 !important">@kallumsbathrooms</p>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td valign="top">
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td width="24" style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:14px; font-weight:700; color:#384241;">
                                              <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/social-pinterest_dark.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" /></a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:14px; font-weight:400; color:#647875;">
                                              <p stlye="margin:0 !important">/kallumsbathroom</p>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table width="640" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

          <td width="640px" valign="center"><img src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Slider-Test-3-1024x597-8.jpg" width="640px" height="auto" alt="" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Hiya! Thanks for responding
Sorry I dont think my instructions were very clear

the image here https://ibb.co/wCL5pn2

shows what i mean more clearly

like i said, the code looks fine when i run it here, but when viewed in the email client it does this!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML did not open and close elements properly.
There are a lot of unnecessary elements. This will be use fewer HTML elements.

Wrap the contents with `<html>` tag to display CSS correctly.
Always use custom class name with prefix such as `htmlemail-xxx` to prevent duplicate with something else.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700);
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
}
img {
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
}
p {
    margin: 0px !important;
}
a {
    color: inherit !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
/* .hidden-mobile was removed because it is not in use. */
.main-htmlemail-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 0;
    width: 640px;
}
.main-htmlemail-table td,
.main-htmlemail-table th {
    padding: 0;
}
.main-htmlemail-table .htmlemail-icon {
    height: 16px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 16px;
}
.main-htmlemail-table .htmlemail-text-content {
    color: #647875;
    font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 14px;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
}
.main-htmlemail-table tr:nth-child(2) .htmlemail-text-content {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.main-htmlemail-table tr:last-child .htmlemail-text-content {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.htmlemail-column-left {
    width: 60%;
}
.htmlemail-column-left-content {
    background-color: #efefef;
}
.htmlemail-column-right {
    width: 40%;
}
.main-htmlemail-table .htmlemail-head-row {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.htmlemail-head1 {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.htmlemail-headsub {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<table class="main-htmlemail-table" width="640">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="htmlemail-column-left htmlemail-head-row">
                <p class="htmlemail-head1">Libby Stonehawk</p>
                <p class="htmlemail-headsub">Website Manager</p>
            </td>
            <td class="htmlemail-column-right htmlemail-head-row">
                <img src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/kallumslogotrans-white-2.png" alt="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="htmlemail-text-content htmlemail-column-left-content">
                <img class="htmlemail-icon" src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/icon-map_dark.png" alt=""> 
                100 Lower Richmond Road, London, SW15 1LN
            </td>
            <td class="htmlemail-text-content">
                <img class="htmlemail-icon" src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/social-facebook_dark.png" alt="">
                /kallumsbathrooms
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="htmlemail-text-content htmlemail-column-left-content">
                <img class="htmlemail-icon" src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/icon-phone_dark.png" alt=""> 
                07941073079
            </td>
            <td class="htmlemail-text-content">
                <img class="htmlemail-icon" src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/social-twitter_dark.png" alt="">
                @KallumsBathroom
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="htmlemail-text-content htmlemail-column-left-content">
                <img class="htmlemail-icon" src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/icon-email_dark.png" alt=""> 
                libby@kallumsbathrooms.co.uk
            </td>
            <td class="htmlemail-text-content">
                <img class="htmlemail-icon" src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/social-instagram_dark.png" alt="">
                @kallumsbathrooms
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="htmlemail-text-content htmlemail-column-left-content">
                <img class="htmlemail-icon" src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/icon-web_dark.png" alt=""> 
                kallumsbathrooms.co.uk
            </td>
            <td class="htmlemail-text-content">
                <img class="htmlemail-icon" src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/social-pinterest_dark.png" alt="">
                /kallumsbathroom
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="main-htmlemail-table" width="640">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="https://kallumsbathrooms.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Slider-Test-3-1024x597-8.jpg" alt="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

The result on Gmail and outlook.com are now same.
I don't have Outlook 365, sorry.
[image: HTML email on Gmail and outlook.com]